# Area of Triangle Problem

Tags: triangles, area

In Triangle $DEF$, $P$ is mid point of $EF$ and $Q$ is the midpoint of $DP$. The area of triangle $DQF$ is $6 \ cm^2$. We need to find the area of triangle $EQF$.

I tried many ways to solve it but could only conclude that area of triangle $DEP$ and $DPF$ are the same. I could not proceed from there. How do I find the area of $EQF$?

Comment: Notice that all the 4 small triangle have the same size.

Comment: Can you please explain more in details - how 4 triangle DQF, FQP, PQE and DQE have same size - by what concept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Let $FH$ the height of the triangle $DQF$ for the basis $DQ$. It is the height also of the triangle $PFQ$ and, since $DQ=PQ$ these two triangle have the same area.

Now do the same reasoning for the triangles $PFQ$ and $PEQ$.

Comment: Please let me know how height of the triangle DQF is height also of the triangle PFQ ?

Comment: Because it is orthogonal to $DQ$, so also to $QP$ that is on the same line $DP$.